# Export multiple csv file using different filename in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

I am new to python.
After researching some code based on my idea which is extracting historical stock data,
I have now working code(see below) when extracting individual name and exporting it to a csv file

```
import investpy
import sys
sys.stdout = open("extracted.csv", "w")
df = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock='JFC',
                                        country='philippines',
                                        from_date='25/11/2020',
                                        to_date='18/12/2020')
print(df)
sys.stdout.close()
```

Now,
I'm trying to make it more advance.
I want to run this code multiple times automatically with different stock name(about 300 plus name) and export it respectively.

I know it is possible but I cannot search the exact terminology to this problem.
Hoping for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store the stock's name as a list and then iterate through the list and save all the dataframes into separate files.

```
import investpy
import sys
stocks_list = ['JFC','AAPL',....] # your stock lists
for stock in stocks_list:
   df = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock=stock,
                                        country='philippines',
                                        from_date='25/11/2020',
                                        to_date='18/12/2020')
  print(df)
  file_name = 'extracted_'+stock+'.csv'
  df.to_csv(file_name,index=False)
```

Comment: I think you mean `stock=stock` instead of`stock='JFC'`. Otherwise, this will write the same file 4 times.

Comment: Thanks. when I added three stock name in stocks_list as trial, then I executed the code, I get only one file csv, and that one file csv is the last name in the stocks_list. I think there's missing line to repeat each in the list?

Comment: @DavidErickson, I tried the 'stock=stock', but there's only one file in the output. that one file is the last name in the 'stocks_list'. the other names was not exported.

Comment: @LeoM IS `df.to_csv(file_name,index=False)` inside our outside your for loop? It should be indise.

Comment: @DavidErickson, thanks. I now realized that indentation is important in python. Thanks for the help from you and Rajat. It's now working!